# JavaScript load order and anonymous function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

In my html file, I am loading two external javascript files that does some dom manipulation, the first one  simply prepares the page (injecting some div and contents) in the html. And the second one locates those divs that were just injected and then try and does some stuffs with it.

```
var app = {
    init: function () {
        // event handler goes here
        app.alertMe('Hello');
        app.loadContent();
        app.insertDiv();
    },
    loadContent: function() {
        $('#div1').load('../html/demo_test.html');
    },
    insertDiv: function() {
        $('#div2').append('<strong>YEEEEEEAP</strong>');
    },
    alertMe: function(a) {
        alert(a);
    }

};

$(function () {
    app.init();
})
```

The second one is [this](https://github.com/amoffat/bootstrap-application-wizard/blob/master/src/bootstrap-wizard.js) bootstrap library.  My html file is as follows

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>A</title>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="page_prep.js">
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        body
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstap_lib.js">
</html>
```

Although I have the load order in the right order, the library seem to be loading before my custom.js this end up causing the actions not to work because the divs that need be present are not found. Careful debugging has proven that the divs were getting injected afterwards.

Any reason why that might be the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are deferring the injection until the page has completed loading, where the bootstrap script runs as soon as the browser downloads it.

Move your script file to just above yout bootstrap script, and change this:

```
$(function () { //This defers execution
    app.init();
})
```

to this:

```
app.init(); //This executes immediately
```